# How to control data flow for a combination of pagination, select filter and search with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm in charge of maintaining an old project using jQuery and PHP. I have problem of making a combination of pagination, select filter and search on a list of div. Currently, my approach is using built-in hide() and show() functions in jQuery to render data for those 3 features. For example, when user paginate, I hide() all div in prev page. and show() divs in next page. However, I'm struggle to manage the data flow between 3 features. Like when I paginate away first and then select some filter. The data list for pagination is not correct anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Is the data coming from the server side (php)?

What you need to try and achieve is a fixed / known set of items that you can filter, search and paginate through. In that order. Certainly with pagination coming last.

Obviously if you have a set of results based on some criteria (a blank search or blank filter) the amount of pages in the result-set are going to be different to what you would have if you have a non-blank search or filter. You need to take that in to account.

I would suggest that when search or filter change, you should be going back to page 1. Pagination is ***related*** to the results you have, whereas the search and filter ***determine*** the results you have. Does that make sense?

I would apply the search and/or filter first, to figure out how many pages I have, then reset the current page to 1.